# Showing 500 Error instead 404 after .htaccess configuration

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've recently added following lines to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

What I'm trying to achieve:
For PHP files:

```
example.com/abc.php should be redirected as example.com/abc
example.com/abc/ should be redirected as example.com/abc
example.com/abc should load as example.com/abc
```

For Directories, load with normal behavior:
Note: xyz is a directory

```
example.com/xyz should load as example.com/xyz/
example.com/xyz/ should load as example.com/xyz/
```

The problem is if someone tries example.com/abc/bla, it throws 500 error instead of 404.
Can someone help to modify the above .htaccess lines to fix the 500 error issue?

Comment: I am assuming you get the 500 error for any page with the current .htaccess? Or is it only happening on the one example you gave?

Comment: @Kinglish its throwing 500 only for example.com/abc/anything
for other non existing pages like example.com/blabla is throwing 400 error without any issue

Comment: @ShafeequeM, 500 internal error is from server, could you please do let us know if you have any more rules apart from these?

Comment: Comment out all lines, and add them back one by one.  It will tell you which line has an issue.  Also put `LogLevel debug` and check you log files.  500 is an internal server error, so apache does not like something in your configuraiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many corrections, i got this issue resolved.
Here is final code of htaccess

```
# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
#Enforce a no-trailing-slash policy.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
# 404 ANY URL WITH ADDITIONAL PATH INFO ##
RewriteCond %{PATH_INFO} .
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

This code does the following

```
example.com/abc.php redirecting as example.com/abc
example.com/abc/ redirecting as example.com/abc
example.com/abc showing as example.com/abc
example.com/abc/nopage redirecting to 404
```